# Could Dark matter manipulation meet the negative energy requirements for an Alcubierre drive?

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy, warp-drives

The biggest issue with the Alcubierre drive is that in order for it to expand the space behind the spacecraft, it would require negative mass with repulsive gravity. No such negative mass is known to exist.

Imagine if in future, we could somehow manipulate dark matter. If we were to evacuate the dark matter from a region of space, that space would then expand, as it would no longer be contracted by the gravity of the dark matter. It might even appear positively warped compared to the rest of space with dark matter.

Would this expansion of space by the removal of dark matter functionally meet the negative mass requirement of an Alcubierre drive?

Comment: Nothing special about dark matter in this context, just use normal (baryonic) matter instead. Will it work? ;)

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Dark matter has positive energy. This is easily seen by considering its gravitational effects, where it shows up as ordinary, *added* mass in a system such as a galaxy.

Comment: But would REMOVING dark matter cause that space to expand without the dark matter's gravity contracting it, and would that EXPANSION of space suit the needs of an Alcubierre drive?

Comment: @Ben Warner: Sure, but not any way different than removing any other matter world. And no, because for one, there's very little in any part of space so even if you removed it all it would make little difference, but for another, because $T^{00}$ is an _absolute_ measure of energy and it must be _absolutely_ negative for the Alcubierre bubble, i.e. "negative energy" here means an energy level below that of a perfect vacuum.